# Aura Session 2.x - CSRF

Tags: php, session, csrf

I have a question if anyone had the opportunity to use Aura Session 2.x? If so, I need help ...

My problem is that I have no idea what I'm supposed to call (?) For the CSRF to work. Unfortunately, but from the example I didn't learn anything. I can't apply it in practice.

Link to the example: [Aura Session 2.x CSRF](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Session#session-security)

My code: `

```
$session_factory = new \Aura\Session\SessionFactory;
$session = $session_factory->newInstance($_COOKIE);

#It seems to me that there is a problem with that
$user = $session->getSegment('Vendor\Package\User');

$unsafe = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'|| $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'DELETE';

#$user->auth->isValid() not work
#Notice: Undefined property: Aura\Session\Session::$auth
#Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isValid() on null
if($unsafe && $user->auth->isValid()){
    $csrf_value = $_POST['__csrf_value'];
    $csrf_token = $session->getCsrfToken(); #it works

    echo !$csrf_token->isValid($csrf_value) ? 'This looks like a cross-site request forgery.' : 'This looks like a valid request.';
} else {
    echo 'CSRF attacks only affect unsafe requests by authenticated users.';
}
```

`

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Comment: Hello Flicly and welcome, please, share the code you've tried so we will be able to help you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you read the documentation and [**attempted to solve the problem yourself**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)? Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Answer (score 0):

The code "$user->auth->isValid()" shown in the documentation example https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Session#session-security refers to the "isValid()" idiom of the Aura.Auth library https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Auth#service-idioms, but the CSRF mechanism does not necessarily require the user to be logged in. It is therefore not mandatory to check user authentication, and in any case you do not necessarily need to use the Aura.Auth library, you can also implement your own authentication control system.